# Why my local storage (Userdefaults) is empty every time I close the app completely (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, local-storage

I have a class in UIViewController

```
class myArrayDataStructure {
    static var myArray = Array<String>() // the singleton array
    private init() {} // prevents unwanted access
}
```

I ask a user to enter a string and store it using a button as follows:

```
 @IBAction func EnterAction(_ sender: Any) {
     if let sContent = TextF.text {
         // append it to the global singleton array
         myArrayDataStructure.myArray.append(sContent)
         UserDefaults.standard.set(myArrayDataStructure.myArray, forKey: "items")}
```

In another viewController, I am pulling the array and display it in a tableView. My identifier cell called "Cell":

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return myArrayDataStructure.myArray.count
    }

  let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        let returnedItems = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "items") ?? [String]()
        let tempLabel = returnedItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = tempLabel + " Good Job"
        return cell
```

The code is working perfectly and I am able to store and display items in the table, but if I double click the home button and re-open the app, the table is empty. How can I keep the saved items in the table even after closing the app completely.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let returnedItems = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "items") ?? [String]()
        for item in returnedItems{
            totalAmount.text = item + " Miles"    // totalAmount is a label under the table
        }

        print(returnedItems)
        table.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Show your `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: From the code you posted you only set the array in the UserDefaults but never read from it.

Comment: Now show how you initialize `myArrayDataStructure.myArray` from `UserDefaults`.

Comment: @rmaddy That is all what I have in the second viewController. Now when I close the app and re-open, I am able to see the data still in the table. But when I double click on home and close it completely, the data is gone. If I have to initialize anything more, I am not sure how to do it. I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: That's because you never load the data from `UserDefaults` when your app restarts.

Comment: I though Userdefaults.set to save and Userdefauld.standard.StringArray to retrieve a String array  which I have both of them. Would you please just be more specific or tell me a method name I can read about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue is that you are not populating `myArrayDataStructure.myArray` when your app reloads.

You are also not making very good use of your global array. You are not using in your `cellForRowAt` method. You are not using it in your `viewDidAppear` method.

You do use it in your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `EnterAction` methods.

At a minimum you need to update your code as follows:

Start by loading the `UserDefaults` into your global array:

```
class myArrayDataStructure {
    static var myArray = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "items") ?? [String]()
    private init() {} // prevents unwanted access
}
```

And then update your view controller to use the global array consistently:

Your `cellForRowAt`:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
let tempLabel = myArrayDataStructure.myArray[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = tempLabel + " Good Job"
return cell
```

Your `viewDidAppear`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    for item in myArrayDataStructure.myArray {
        totalAmount.text = item + " Miles"
    }

    table.reloadData()
}
```

Note that your loop in `viewDidAppear` will only show the last value in the array. It's kind of pointless.